# Expected number of rolls until finishing the snakes and ladders game

Tags: probability, expected-value

The Question that I encountered is as follows.

> You are playing a game of snakes and ladders. You start at square 1,
> and each turn you roll a d6 and move the corresponding number of
> squares. When you reach at least square 25, you stop. There is also a
> snake which connects squares 5 and 20 (i.e. if you land on 20, you
> immediately move down to 5), and there is a ladder from 10 to 15 (so
> if you land on 10, you immediately move up to 15). What is the
> expected number of rolls until you finish the game?

According to the solution, we can start by expected number of rolls when we assum there are no snakes and ladders. If we get this expectation, than we can add expected number of rolls for adding snake, and substracting expected number of rolls when ladder is added.

I get the part about the expected number when no snakes and ladders. Since expectation of one roll is 3.5, we could divide 24/3.5, but due to condition that 25 is not the terminal number, but the least of the terminal, we could come up with estimate of 24 + 1.75 as the terminal, which makes Expectation as 25.75/3.5. (This would not be the accurate, but quite close)

The part I don't get is about the snakes and ladders part.

> Now consider the snake. The average roll is 3.5, so the probability of
> landing on any individual square is 1/3.5 (note this clearly doesn’t
> hold in small cases -e.g. your probability of landing on square 2 is
> only 1/6 -but for larger numbers it holds with extremely high
> accuracy). So the number of attempts until we get past the snake is
> geometric with probability (1 − 1/3.5) = 2.5/3.5, meaning the expected
> number of times we hit the snake is (3.5/2.5) −1 = 0.4.

Especially when it comes to probability of landing on any individual square is 1/3.5, and how the number of attempts are derived.
In addition, I also don't get the part about expected number of times we hit the snake being (3.5/2.5) -1, why do we substract 1?

Could anyone explain how these logics are set?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The $3.5$ is not exact, but if you rolled $100$ times on an unbounded basic board then you might expect to be at or near square $350$ (the average value of a roll is $\frac{1+2+3+4+5+6}{6}=3.5$), so would have landed on about a proportion of about $\frac{100}{350}$ of the squares up to that point.

Comment: I'm sorry, but could you explain a bit about how you got 100/350?

Comment: If you are at or near square $350$ and have landed on $100$ squares to get there then you have landed on about $\frac{100}{350}$ of the squares

Comment: Oh I understand. Thanks